# Como atualizar Modelo com relacionamento de tabelas no Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent, laravel-8

sou iniciante em laravel e gostaria de ajuda, eu tenho uma classe Atendimento que está relacionada com uma classe Situação.

Em minha regra de negocio, quando um atendimento for "deletado" pelo usuário, eu irei apenas mudar a situação dele para cancelado.

Porem não estou encontrando uma maneira de atualizar o Atendimento, alterando a situação dele para a cancelada. Na tabela de Atendimento preciso atualizar o situacao_id para a chave estrangeira da tabela situacao que corresponde ao cancelado.

Também aceito sugestões sobre como melhorar esse código e também os relacionamentos entre classes.

PS: O Controller pode parecer confuso, pois tentei várias maneiras.

A Classe de Atendimento

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class Atendimento extends Model
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;



    protected $fillable = [
        'situacao_id',
        'sexo_id',
        'atuacao_id',
        'necessidade_id',
        'nome',
        'idade',
        'anoscontribuicao',
        'whats',
        'email',
        'mensagem',


    ];

    public function situacao(){

        return $this->belongsTo(Situacao::class);

    }
   
}
```

A classe de situação do atendimento

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Situacao extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'descricao',


    ];

    public function atendimento()    {

        return $this->hasMany(Atendimento::class,'situacao_id');
    }
}
```

As situações do Atendimento

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O controller

```
public function destroy (Request $request, $id)
    {
        $atendimento = new Atendimento();
        $atendimento = $atendimento->find($id);


        $situacao = new Situacao();
        $situacao = DB::table('situacaos')->where('descricao','=','Cancelado')->get();
        $atendimento->situacao = DB::table('situacaos')->where('descricao','=','Cancelado')->get();
         

        // oque eu faço aqui para atualizar o atendimento com a nova situação? $atendimento->save(); não funcionou.

        $atendimentos = new Atendimento();
        $atendimentos = Atendimento::simplePaginate(10);
        $situacaos = Situacao::all();
        $sexos = Sexo::all();
        return view('atendimento.index',['atendimentos' => $atendimentos, 'situacaos' => $situacaos, 'sexos' => $sexos] );

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Primeiramente quando você quer localizar um item em uma tabela você não precisa fazer o "New" Collection();

Segundamente, achei um tanto confuso esse código:

```
 $atendimentos = new Atendimento();
    $atendimentos = Atendimento::simplePaginate(10);
    $situacaos = Situacao::all();
    $sexos = Sexo::all();
    return view('atendimento.index',['atendimentos' => $atendimentos, 'situacaos' => $situacaos, 'sexos' => $sexos] );
```

Porque você retorna uma "view" quando está em uma função que retornará um GET, e um destroy é um DELETE, portanto ao invés de retornar a view com as collections você só redireciona para a view, já que a função "index" irá entregar o código necessário.

```
return redirect('/rota-web-que-entrega-essa-pagina');
```

Outra coisa, como você não está deletando um código, utilize o método HTTP "PUT", já que está apenas fazendo uma alteração no código, então recomendo não utilizar a função destroy, e sim "update".

para atualizar a linha do atendimento você pode:

```
$atendimento = Atendimento::find($id);
$atendimento->update([
     'situacao_id' => 4
]);
```

Utilizei o ID = 4 porque a princípio é o id do cancelado.

Não sei o que você está enviando no request, mas provavelmente é o ID do atendimento que você deseja cancelar, então ele vai encontrar o atendimento e alterar a situacao_id dele.

Answer (score -2):

Algumas observações:

1. Como o seu código está em português, você precisa definir o nome das tabelas no seu modelo, caso contrário o Laravel não vai conseguir identificar automaticamente o nome das tabelas. Para isso, é só usar o `$table = 'nome'`.
2. Não sei como está as suas tabelas, imagino que deve ter relacionamentos. Talvez seja necessário adicionar nos relacionamentos do seu modelo (especificar o foreign id, etc.). Exemplo: `$this->belongsTo(Situacao::class, 'id_relacionamento_aqui');`
3. Utilize o `firstOrFail()` se você realmente precisa do valor para a proxima query. Ex.: Você precisa do id de situação cancelado, então esse valor deve ser retornado, caso contrario sua aplicação vai falhar.
4. O método `update()` já faz o `save()` e + algumas coisas (por exemplo, se você tem eventos definidos para serem emitidos ao atualizar, ou atualizar colunas como updated_at). Caso queria utilizar o save, `->fillable($atributos)->save()` faz o mesmo.
5. Eu alterei os seu $fillable = [...] para $guarded = []. Caso queria proteger algum campo de mass assignment, adicione ele no array.

Adicionei alguns comentários no código abaixo também.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class Atendimento extends Model
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'atendimentos';

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function situacao()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Situacao::class);
    }
   
}



<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Situacao extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];

    const DESCRICAO_CANCELADO = "Cancelado";

    public function atendimento() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Atendimento::class, 'situacao_id');
    }
}


<?php

// Seu controller
// ...
//....
// Encontra uma situação com descricao cancelado. 
// 
// first() retorna apenas um resultado
// get() vai te retornar uma Collection (vários resultados)
$situacaoCancelada = Situacao::where('descricao', Situacao::DESCRICAO_CANCELADO)->firstOrFail();

// Captura o atendimento pelo id
// 
// firstOrFail() para emitir um erro, caso não encontre o valor
// se falhar, ira retornar uma exception ModelNotFoundException
$atendimento = Atendimento::where('id', $id)->update([
    // Atualiza o id da situacao para cancelada
    'situacao' => $situacaoCancelada->getKey()
]);

return view('atendimento.index', [
    'atendimentos' => Atendimento::simplePaginate(10), 
    'situacoes' => Situacao::all(), 
    'generos' => Sexo::all()
])
```